# How to prove the relation between column space of $A$ and $A^2$?

Tags: vector-spaces

If $A$ is square,

1. show that $N(A) \subset N(A^2)$,
2. Show that $C(A^2) \subset C(A)$,

where $N(A)$ represents the nullspace of $A$ and $C(A)$ the column space of $A$.

I proved the first one.

---

For any $x \in N(A)$, it satisfies that $Ax=0$. Thus, $A^2x=A(Ax)=A0=0$, which implies that $x$ is always belonging to $N(A^2)$.

---

However, I failed to prove the second one.

Can someone help me to prove the number 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y \in C(A^2)$. Then there is $x$ such that $y=A^2x$. With $z:=Ax$ we get:

$y=Az \in C(A)$.

Comment: Very concise... Thank you very much. I am impressed with this short and exact proof.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Show that $C(AB)\subset C(A)$ for any matrix $B$ (of an appropriate shape). What's a good working definition of the column space?